# SpecFlow does not discover tests or I get an error message

Tags: c#, specflow, specrun

For starters: I am new to Visual Studio and SpecFlow in general.

Following the getting started documentation on SpecFlow I get 2 different outcomes depending on what type of project I start.

Unit Test Project: in this type of projects, the test's aren't recognized by the runner at all. Only the "SpecRun Evaluation" test runs.

MSTest Test Project (.NET Core): in this type of projects, the tests are always passing but I do get an error in the Tests output:
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: message"
and that's caused by a "generator"

I'm doing all this on a typical Windows 10 Pro.
I have tried both on VS 2017 and 2019.
I have tried re-doing the whole process in case I've missed something.
Also tried updating packages. Something that maybe should be noted, Unit Test Projects do not generate an App.config file.

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Tests.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public class CalculatorSteps
    {
        [Given(@"I have entered (.*) into the calculator")]
        public void GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(int p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

        [Given(@"I have also entered (.*) into the calculator")]
        public void GivenIHaveAlsoEnteredIntoTheCalculator(int p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

        [When(@"I press add")]
        public void WhenIPressAdd()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("add pressed");
        }


        [Then(@"the result should be (.*) on the screen")]
        public void ThenTheResultShouldBeOnTheScreen(int p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

    }
}
```

I would pretty much expect for the tests to run and to get some kind of a feedback when I intentionally throw an exception in a test.

All of this is just a task for a job application, but what I've provided is the default feature file that gets generated, as both situations have that outcome. I already have an idea how to complete the task and here I am stuck on the Set Up for hours... I really hope it's just my stupidity/inexperience.

.csproj: https://codeshare.io/5zxk0W

Comment: You mention .NET Core, so I assume you use version 3 of Specflow. You use a json file for configuration in that version, not app.config. Try to set up Specflow according to [this](https://specflow.org/2018/specflow-3-public-preview-now-available/) page.

Comment: @MikaS Thanks, it seems that doesn't make a difference though, unless I do need to configure a json, because it does say it's not something required. Tests are still not recognized except for the "SpecRun Evaluation". I still need to try on another project, hopefully that'll work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is for SpecFlow 2.*. With SpecFlow 3 you only need to add the `SpecFlow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation` NuGet package to your project.

You missed one step to enable the MSBuild integration.

You have to put following code at the end of csproj in the  tag.

```
<Target Name="AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject">
    <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.feature.cs" Exclude="@(Compile)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

It is described in https://specflow.org/2019/generating-code-behind-files-using-msbuild/ - Enabling MSBuild Code Behind Generation
Classic Project System - Step 2